# SQL Select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

**Tables**

> > **MENUS**:  UId name start_date stop_date price xdele last_editor,
> >     last_editor_Ip last_edit_date and version
> >
> > **MENU_ITEMS**: uid, ref_menu ref_menu_version ref_type ref_item
> >     ref_item_version position xdele last_editor, last_editor_ip
> >     last_edit_date and version
> >
> > **PRODUCTS**: uid name description price quantity id_um ref_image xdele
> >     last_editor, last_editor_ip, last_edit_date and version
> >
> > **PRODUCT_GROUPS**: uid name description ref_Menu ref_menu version and the
> >     others above
> >
> > **CLASSIFICATION**: uid ref_product ref_product_version ref_group and
> >     ref_group_version

SO: classification table unifies products to product groups. each menu has menu items from that table. 
I need a select query that gets all products from a menu (ref_type is 0 if it's product and 1 if it's product group). I can get all products if they're individual (ref_type=0), but if they're in groups i don't know how to get them.

Thank you!

Comment: I did it in java, but I want to do it in SQL - I don't know how.

Comment: Have you tried INNER JOIN? If not do so.

Comment: For what DBMS? Oracle, MySQL...? The query can be very different

Comment: The database is PostgreSQL

Comment: please provide some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join MENUS and MENU_ITEM, I'm not strong in PostgreSQL, so, my syntax should not work.
try something similar:

```
 SELECT <what you need> 
 FROM MENUS, MENU_ITEM, PRODUCTS
 WHERE MENUS.uid = MENU_ITEM.UID
    AND MENUS.uid = PRODUCT.UID
    AND MENU_ITEM.ref_id = 1
```

is this what you need, or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: This is how I join menu items to menus, it's correct. What i need are the products in a menu given by menuitems ref_item. The problem is how do i get the products whether they are individual or in groups.

Comment: Is not enough add the PRODUCTS Table in the join and check again uid?